# Can I declare a function inside a class without body in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I was referring to the `UIKit.UITableView` file and I noticed that all the functions inside UITableView class are written without their body. I tried to do the same in my project but Xcode wouldn't let me do so. Can someone explain how was that possible in the source file?

Below is a sample snippet from there.

```
open func insertRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)

open func deleteRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)

@available(iOS 5.0, *)
open func moveRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, to newIndexPath: IndexPath)

@available(iOS 3.0, *)
open func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)
```

Comment: You are looking at a generated interface file, which is not actually Swift source code.

Comment: @Sweeper Is there any possibility to see the actual source file?

Comment: No. UIKit is close source.

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3108-viewing-the-interface-of-your-swift-code)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this empty function declaration? Maybe what you actually need is to define a protocol (Interface) ?

Comment: @DimaG No I know about Protocols. I am new to Swift, and I am trying to get a better understanding of delegates and protocols pattern. That's why I wanted to have a look at the practical implementation of it, and surprised by these empty functions inside classes. Now I got it.

Comment: What you're currently seeing is like a "header file". It's just declaration. iOS code isn't Open-source (some part are though). And in this case, it's more about Delegate, so it's not "implemented really".

Answer (score 0):

yes with empty function declaration

```
class myClass  {
     func myFunc?() 
}
```

when you need it you write the body like
in different class you make

```
myClassObj.myFunc = { 
    code 
}
```